# Water's Specific Heat Capacity as an Outlier

Tags: thermodynamics, water

Can the specific heat capacity of water being ridiculously high as compared to other substances be explained at a molecular scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water is polar and is not one line or round.  It takes energy to break the polar bonds.  With  the V shape it takes more energy to spin it.  Many degrees of freedom for water to vibrate and rotate.

I would not call water an outlier.  Alcohol is close to water.